# Creating table in other schema oracle using select

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How do I create table in different schema of local database using linked database ?

```
create table schema1.table1 select * from  schema.table@LinkedDB;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close - use:

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.table1 AS (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.table@LinkedDB);
```

You can [read more about it here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php).

Comment: It shows error SQL Error: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM' I am not using system am I?

Comment: Sounds like user schema1 has it's default tablespace set to SYSTEM. That is never a good idea. Change the default with "ALTER USER schema1 DEFAULT TABLESPACE xxxxx;" where xxxx is the new default.